# JQuery - move Form opening Tag

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have this HTML with a form and a select element.

```
...
<select id="sQuantity" name="sQuantity">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
...
<form name="myform" method="post" action="/someplace">
<input type="hidden" name="forminput" value="" />
...
</form>
...
```

What I am trying to is to move the form opening tag above a select element which is above and outside the form.
Because I cannot alter the template where the HTML is assembled, I cannot do this by the usual means.

Is it possible to do this with jquery?

I don't want to touch any of the elements in the form, and everything should stay where it is.
I only want to move the opening tag of the form so it looks like this:

```
...
<form name="myform" method="post" action="/someplace">
<select id="sQuantity" name="sQuantity">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
...
<input type="hidden" name="forminput" value="" />
...
</form>
...
```

EDIT:

I cannot move the select element, i have to move the form.
This is because the select element would loose its Position and styling because the form is much further down in the document.

Comment: Moving the `select` element within the form will be easier as it has no nested elements

Comment: Yes, it's possible with jQuery. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Since i dont know enough about JQuery i havent tried to play around. also i dont know if it is even possible to move elements into forms after page creation, are those elements still posted on submit?

Comment: I cannot move the select element, since its styling and position will be lost because the form is much further down in the document

Comment: @JoséMarquez You cannot move an opening tag of an element once it is a dom node. YOu must instead move the select into the form. If that will impact the position of your select, that's too bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the answers given, I decided to give my own answer. I've made something that works, at least as long as we're sure there's no other element with the name `myform`.

```
var elements = [];
var elem = $("#sQuantity");
while (elem.attr('name') != "myform")
{
    var next = elem.next();
    elements.push(elem);
    elem = next;
}
for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    $("form[name='myform']").prepend(elements[i]);
```

It gets a sibling with `next()`, then it checks if the elements name is equal to "myform". If not, it adds it to the array called `elements`, and proceeds with the next, until it finds the element with the name "myform", which is supposed to be the form. Then, starting from the bottom of the array, it prepends the elements to the form, thus preserving the order.

[Here's a jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/MCNsG/1/).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$select=$("#sQuantity").clone();
$("#sQuantity").remove();
$("form[name='myform']").prepend($select);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MCNsG/)

Comment: This won't work I guess if there are other things between the `select` and the `form` (note the ... between them at the question)

Comment: exactly, also i cannot move the select element for reasons i specified in my edit.

Comment: @JoséMarquez If you can use jquery and javascript you CAN move anything you like. Your comment about not being able to alter the HTML does not apply to dynamically moving the elements on the page. If there are other elements between the `select` and the `form` elements you should post more of your markup so we can suggest a better alternative. As it currently stands, this answer does answer your question based on what you have provided .+1

Comment: @leemo what i meant was i cannot alter the HTML in the template which produces this mess in the first place. i know i can alter it afterwards with jquery, thats why im asking how to do it :)

Comment: @leemo do you suggest i should post hundreds of line of html code which doesnt play any role in the question? why would i do that? i clearly suggested that there is code in between with "..."

Comment: @JoséMarquez not at all. I only suggest that you make your question clearer with all the salient information. AlessandroMinoccheri's answer was correct with the information you had given him at the time.

Comment: @leemo thats why i edited my question, after i discovered that the question could be misunderstood. TGO understood it even before the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the `select` element should, according to your description, produce the same result, and will be alot easier:

```
var $sQuantity = $("#sQuantity").detach();
$('form[name="myForm"]').prepend($sQuantity);
```

To move the opening tag only you need to look at [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
var myForm = $('form[name="myForm"]'​);
myForm.​​​​​​children().unwrap()​;
$('.sectionToWrap'​).wrap(myForm);​
```

Comment: I cannot move the select element, i have to move the form. This is because the select element would loose its Position and styling because the form is much further down in the document.